# Reminder check box not selected first Time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

[image]

I am new to Swift I can used reminder check box in login page working fine.

1. when Reminder checkBox select show the credential in log text Field it's working
2. when Reminder checkBox unselect credential is clear from the log text Field  working

but when logout after if I can click reminder checkbox to unselect the reminder checkBox it's not selecting first time when I click Double its selecting.

This is the code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


      let checkviewapper = UserDefaults.standard
      let logindata = UserDefaults.standard
      let data = checkviewapper.integer(forKey:"checked")

        print("data values is ",data)
        if(data == 1)
        {

          RmdButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
          emailText.text = logindata.string(forKey: "emaild_default")
          passwordText.text = logindata.string(forKey: "password_default")

        }
        else
        {

            emailText.text = ""
            passwordText.text = ""
            RmdButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck.jpeg"), for: .normal)

        }
    }


    @IBAction func checkBox(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let defautls = UserDefaults.standard
        defautls.removeObject(forKey:"checked")

        defautls.synchronize()

       if unchecked {


             let defautls = UserDefaults.standard
             defautls.set(unchecked, forKey: "checked")
             defautls.synchronize()

            if let myLoadedString = defautls.string(forKey: "checked") {

            }

            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
            print("checked inside")
            unchecked = false
        }
        else {
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck.jpeg"), for: .normal)
            print("uncheckinside")
            unchecked = true
        }

    }
```

Where I did mistake, how to set the reminder CheckBox uncheck at First Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let defautls = UserDefaults.standard

    if defautls.bool(forKey: "checked") == true {
    {
        RmdButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
        emailText.text = logindata.string(forKey: "emaild_default")
        passwordText.text = logindata.string(forKey: "password_default")

    }
    else
    {
        emailText.text = ""
        passwordText.text = ""
        RmdButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck.jpeg"), for: .normal)

    }
}
}

@IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let defautls = UserDefaults.standard

        if defautls.bool(forKey: "checked") == false {
            defautls.set(true, forKey: "checked")
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
            print("checked inside")
            unchecked = false
        }
        else {
            defautls.set(false, forKey: "checked")
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck.jpeg"), for: .normal)
            print("uncheckinside")
            unchecked = true
        }

}
```

and when you tap on logout set the default:-

```
            let defautls = UserDefaults.standard
            defautls.set(false, forKey: "checked")
```